# Add a background image and save it using Python scripting

Tags: python, rendering, scripting

I have a cube and I want to add it on top of a background image using Python scripting

```
import bpy
cam = bpy.context.scene.camera
filepath = r'c:\Home\background\background_image.jpg'

bpy.ops.object.load_background_image(filepath=filepath, filter_image=True, filter_folder=True, view_align=True)
bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
```

But in the output image I can see only the 3d cube with white background.

I got the results I wanted using this tutorial:
https://henryegloff.com/how-to-render-a-background-image-in-blender-2-8/
But I want to accomplish it using only Python Scripts.

Blender cube:

[image]

Output:

[image]